# Looping through array of objects and performing async functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, promise, es6-promise

I am using NextJS and I have an array of assets (images) in my state.  I need to post those images to the API.  I have an object that does this with the following syntax:

```
let response = await api_image.post()
if(response.status !== 201) {
    resolve()
}
```

So for each of the images in the assets array I need to first create a new `api_image` then post it.  I am quite new to promises, and so far from StackOverflow research i have the following code put together:

```
 async postAssetsToAPI(asset) {
        let registrationID = this.registrationID
        return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            let api_image = new api_image()
            api_image.filename = asset.filename
            api_image.uploadOwnerType = 'registration'
            api_image.uploadOwnerID = registrationID
            let response = await api_image.post()
            if(response.status !== 201) {
                resolve()
            }
        })
    }

    async redirectToFinish() {

        let registrationID = this.registrationID
        let success = true
    
        console.log('redirectToUploadMetadata')

        const promises = this.props.assets.map(this.postAssetsToAPI)
        await Promise.all(promises).then(
            () => {console.log('promises succeeded')},
            () => {console.log('promises failed')}
        )

    }
```

This just fails with the console message `promises failed`.  Also, I'm unsure about the `async` inside `new Promise(async(resolve, reject)`, it feels like im just takking on async wherever to get it to work, but I couldnt have the await inside the promise without it.

Whats the best way to achieve this? I need each api_image to post and save data in the database and for a message to display at the end when its done.

Comment: You already have an async function, so you don't need `new Promise`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix and match `async` with `new Promise` and `then` – all you need is

```
async function redirectToFinish() {
  const registrationID = this.registrationID;

  const uploadPromises = this.props.assets.map(async (asset) => {
    const api_image = new api_image();
    api_image.filename = asset.filename;
    api_image.uploadOwnerType = "registration";
    api_image.uploadOwnerID = registrationID;
    const response = await api_image.post();
    if (response.status !== 201) {
      throw new Error("Error uploading image");
    }
  });

  try {
    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("redirectToFinish");
}
```

Comment: if we needed to process the results of the promise as an array, doing something like: `const myAssets = this.props.assets; Promise.all(myAssets.map(asset => {const api_image = new api_image(); api_image.filename = asset.filename; etc(); return api_image.post()})).then((resultList) => {resultList.map(result => handleEachResult(result); )}).catch(err => {handleError(err);}).finally(() => {allPromisesDone(); });` may be helpful, probably?

Comment: Thanks, this works. What confuses me about this is there is no resolve or reject?  How is the promise functioning without these?

Comment: @RichardBridge [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)s always return promises (resolved if a value is returned, rejected if an exception is uncaught).

Comment: @jsN00b That also has way unnecessary uses of `then`.